# Unable to Use Private Feeds in Build Pipelines

Tags: build, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

After the update on 10/27 we are no longer able to create organization level artifacts which was expected as part of Microsoft's change. However, due to this change the only feeds that we can publish to are organizational level feeds (which we are no longer able to create). I am assuming we could also publish to public feeds but I do not want a public project or feed. Any feed that is created now after the update is not found by the build pipeline since it is a project specific feed. I am getting the following error even though the feed exists and I can select it from the dropdown in the classic view (and yaml as well).

[image: Screenshot of Error]

This was working great on Friday last week and for the past several month but now after the update I am unable to connect from my build pipeline to any of the feeds that I create.

Comment: Did you try out below answer? Any good news?

Answer (score 0):

As my test, I can get a feed named "test10021" in my dropdown list.
[image]

And then I get the same warning message with yours.
[image]

I check the feed in my current project Artifacts but find nothing.

[image]

Finally, I find this feed in other project which is in the same organization. And this feed is a public feed, but the project is a private project.

Hope this will help.